# Efficient ways to treat two different items as a single, unique item?

Tags: arrays, nodes, unique

Let's say you have an array of Strings, `['one', '1', 'two', '2']`.

For whatever reason (be imaginative), the elements in this array need to exist independently of one another. But, in one instance, you need to treat pairs (or more) of elements as unique items. For example, in that instance, the elements `'one'` and `'1'` should be treated as a single, unique value.

You will always know which two (or more) elements should be merged together, in that instance, to be reported as a single value.

The strings may not always occur consecutively. For example, it could be `['one', 'two', '1', '2']`, `['2', 'one', '1', 'two']` or `['1', 'two', '2', '1']`.

How would you do it?

My first instinct would be to try and engineer something out of Loadash's [uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) function. But, I'm curious if mapping over the array to merge the elements to be treated as uniqe together would be easier?

Comment: Mhhhh ... would the array always be sorted making the data "together"/consecutive as a pair?

Comment: `[2*i]`  and `[2*i+1]` are the elements.  Do with them what you wish.

Comment: Sorry, no. They wont always be consequtive. I'll update the question to make that clear.

Comment: If they're not consecutive, how do you know which element belongs with which other element(s)?

Comment: It'll be predefined. What I'm working on is reporting error message counts. It's a bit too complicated to explain in the comments, but essentially you'll have two error messages that report different parts of the same thing. But, when looking at a higher level, you'll want to only count them as one error as there's an error with that thing; you don't need to know that theres multiple things wrong with that thing until you get there.

Comment: Programatically, the elements that belong together can be hard-coded as an array, object, whatever you want.

Comment: You can just join all the strings.  If you can choose an appropriate delimiter you can join all the strings with that delimiter.  For example `['one', '1'].join('\0')` will produce a unique value that is different from the one produced by `['on', 'e1'].join('\0')`.  If not, then you can write an element-wise array compare or a property-wise object compare.

Comment: That's something I hadn't considered! Could work quite well. Can you join elements that aren't consecutive? Almost like ['one', 'two', '2', '1'].join('one', '1') ?

Comment: I imagine a _selector_ which is an ordered array of indices letting you access elements of the array in any scattered order, including duplicates.  In the array `['one', '1', 'two', '2']` the selector `[2,3,0]` corresponds to `['two', '2', 'one']`.  i.e.: `selector.map(i => array[i])`  Then the unique value would be `selector.map(i => array[i]).join('\0')`.  Ironically, the selector itself could also be the unique value. `selector.join(',')` is unique for a given input array.  (PS: it's still not very clear to me exactly what you're asking for.  You should put all details in your question.)